# How to retrieve data from external device through Winsock to Microsoft Visual Basic (VB6)

Tags: vb6, winsock, tcp

I need to make an application that needs to retrieve data from an external terminal booking device to my application, with a telnet connection and show it on the txtOutput textbox.

I am pretty new in VB and used some time to learn the basics of the language.

First I created a Standard EXE project and added the Winsock control to the form.
I made a ping-request to the IP address I wanted to have connection too and it works.

Then I want to send a command to the external device. I want the booking-terminal to give me feedback to the txtOutput for me to read.

I made the connection and as much as I can see, I do send my messages to the terminal. But I don't get any responses from it! Nothing from it is viewed on my txtOutput.

How can that be?

Here is my code:

```
Dim IPAddress As String
Dim PortNum As Integer

Private Sub cmdConnect_Click()    
    Winsock.Close
    Winsock.RemoteHost = txtIpaddress.Text
    IPAddress = Winsock.RemoteHost
    PortNum = CStr(txtPortnr.Text)
    If (Val(PortNum) > 65535) Then
        Winsock.RemotePort = (Val(PortNum) - 65535)
        PortNum = Winsock.RemotePort
    Else
        Winsock.RemotePort = Val(PortNum)
        PortNum = Winsock.RemotePort
    End If

    Winsock.Connect

    Module1.send_to_buffer ("Attempting connection to: " & IPAddress & ":" & CStr(PortNum))

    Call wsock_status
    End Sub

Private Sub Winsock_Connect()
    Module1.send_to_buffer ("Succeeded connection to: " & IPAddress & ":" & CStr(PortNum))
    txtSend.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub cmdSend_Click()
Dim strSData As String
Dim message_to_send As String
    If (Winsock.State = 0) Then
        Module1.send_to_buffer ("You need to connect first!")
        txtSend.Text = ""
    Else
        strSData = txtSend.Text
        Winsock.SendData strSData & vbCrLf
        message_to_send = txtSend.Text
        If (message_to_send <> "") Then
            Winsock.SendData message_to_send & vbCrLf
            Module1.send_to_buffer_norm (txtSend.Text)
            txtSend.Text = ""
            txtSend.SetFocus
        Else
            Module1.send_to_buffer ("Nothing to send!")
            txtSend.Text = ""
            txtSend.SetFocus
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub terminalConnector_DataArrival(ByVal bytesTotal As Long)
Dim strData As String
    Winsock.GetData strData

    If (Len(txtOutput.Text) = 0) Then
        txtOutput.Text = strData & vbCrLf
    Else
        txtOutput.Text = txtOutput.Text & strData & vbCrLf
    End If
    End Sub

Private Sub cmdDisconnect_Click()
Dim Counter As Long
    If (Winsock.State <> 0) Then
        Winsock.Close
        Call wsock_status
        Module1.send_to_buffer ("Connection to " & IPAddress & ":" & CStr(PortNum) & " closed.")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Winsock_Close()
    Module1.send_to_buffer ("Disconnected from: " & IPAddress & ":" & CStr(PortNum))
    Winsock.Close
End Sub
```

and Module1 code:

```
Public Function send_to_buffer(text_to_display As String)
    If (Len(terminalConnector.txtOutput.Text) = 0) Then
        terminalConnector.txtOutput.Text = "*** " & text_to_display
    Else
        terminalConnector.txtOutput.Text = terminalConnector.txtOutput.Text & vbCrLf & "*** " & text_to_display & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    End If
End Function

Public Function send_to_buffer_norm(text_to_input As String)
    If (Len(terminalConnector.txtOutput.Text) = 0) Then
        terminalConnector.txtOutput.Text = "> " & text_to_input & vbCrLf
    Else
        terminalConnector.txtOutput.Text = terminalConnector.txtOutput.Text & "> " & text_to_input & vbCrLf
    End If
End Function
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a question here?  We see your code, but you don't indicate what the problem is.  Is there an error when you try to save?

Comment: What is this "terminal" you speak of?  Your answer has significant bearing on any solution.  But just to begin with your program will probably have to be a TCP server, not a client, and in addition most devices called "terminals" require some minimal protocol layer, e.g. Telnet, on top of TCP.

Comment: The terminals that I'm talking about is like the booking terminals at the work you use when you are booking arrival at work.

Comment: Telnet connection is just protocol over TCP/IP; you have to mostly send and receive plain text and some control codes over TCP. I suggest you to learn about telnet protocol - for example here: http://www.pcmicro.com/netfoss/telnet.html - and implement your required subset.

Comment: Hey Arvo, sorry my stupidity but what do you mean by "and implement your required subset"? I need to make this fast as it's a task from my boss and we need to find a solution :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataArrival event is named wrongly :

in your code it is :

```
Private Sub terminalConnector_DataArrival(ByVal bytesTotal As Long)
```

but it should be the name of your winsock control :

```
Private Sub Winsock_DataArrival(ByVal bytesTotal As Long)
```

You can always select the controlname in the combobox on the left above your code window in the IDE and then select the eventname in the combobox on the right above your code window in the IDE, which will put the outlines of the event code in your code window.

Or you can double-click the control on the design window in the IDE, which will bring you to the code window and put the outlines of an event code in your code window .. you can then select the event you want in the combobox on the right above your code window

A side comment : `Winsock` might is not the best name for a winsock control, it is best to give it a more unique same, which could be as simple as `wskConnection` or `wskTerminal`

When you download [MZ-tools](http://www.mztools.com/v3/mztools3.aspx) you can "Review Source Code" which will show you any procedures and variables that will not be called or used in your program ... this will often give an extra hint to misnamed variables or procedures

Comment: Thank you Hrqls, that helped alot, now I receive something back! But I can't read/understand it. The feedbackI got after connected to the terminal is: ÿý↑. What does it mean and is there a way to translate that to readable string?

Comment: the data is probably encoded/encrypted ? do you receive readable data when you use telnet ?

Comment: I get the weird feedback when I use port 23

Comment: then your program is working correctly, and you just have to find a way to decode the received data :)

Comment: numeric data is often stored in as few bits as needed, after which the bits are put after another, and then split into sets of 8 bits to form ascii characters to send .. so for example if the data exists of 8 numbers which are always smallers than 8, then they could be stored in 8 numbers of 3 bits each combined into 24 bits total which can be sent as 3 ascii characters, so instead of receiving 8 numbers you will then receive 3 (encoded) ascii characters ... but there are a lot of different ways to send data, often including some header data ...

Comment: If you know exactly what data you should receive, then maybe we can find out how it was encoded

Comment: As my question is answered I will mark your answer as the right answer and make a new question for this translation of telnet data :)

Answer (score 0):

You Send routine is wrong :

```
Private Sub cmdSend_Click()
  Dim strSData As String
  txtSend.Text = strSData
  Winsock.SendData strSData
End Sub
```

You are showing strSata in txtSend ... while strSData is still an empty string .. after that you send the empty string via the Winsock control

you probably meant :

```
Private Sub cmdSend_Click()
  Dim strSData As String
  strSData = txtSend.Text
  Winsock.SendData strSData
End Sub
```

Which reads txtSend.Text into your string variable, and then sends that via the Winsock control

The server probably wants some special character at the end of your string, so dont forget to add that ... usually you have to add a cariage return :

```
strSData = strSData & vbCr
```

Comment: :) it happens to the best of us :) .... feel free to accept this as the answer to complete this.

Comment: I would, but i'm not finished :/<br>I have updated my question. I can send data and I think I can receive data too, but I don't get any output on my textbox